# Test Run Failed: local variable '' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, sikuli

Long time reader, first time poster!

I've been working on setting up the first piece of automation at my workplace and teaching myself my first programming language at the same time. The end goal is to set up a Sikuli script to run testing overnight.

I keep running into errors that feel like a lack of understanding on basic python principles and I don't have anyone around to teach me.

The function `do_math` parses a .csv file, does some math, and returns those variables in a tuple. I then assign those results into a variable and try to compare them but I keep running into:

```
Test Run Failed: local variable 'D2LAverage' referenced before assignment
```

I've tried assigning D2LAverage in a number of different places, making it global, returning a list vs tuples, but it just keeps getting stuck.

<handler.py>

```
def do_math():
  with open ('C:/Program Files/TrueVision Surgical/DSM/Logs/Latency_' + timestr + '.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
   csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
   line_count = 0
   
   D2L = []
   L2D = []
   
   next(csv_file)
   for row in csv_reader:
     next
     D2L.append(float(row[1]))
     L2D.append(float(row[2]))
     line_count += 1
   else:
     D2LAverage = 0
     L2DAverage = 0
     D2LAverage = float(sum(D2L) / len(D2L))
     L2DAverage = float(sum(L2D) / len(L2D))

   D2Lvar = sum(pow(x-D2LAverage,2) for x in D2L) / len(D2L) # Get varience
   D2Lstd = math.sqrt(D2Lvar) # Calculate STD
   L2Dvar = sum(pow(x-L2DAverage,2) for x in L2D) / len(L2D) # Get varience
   L2Dstd = math.sqrt(L2Dvar) # Calculate STD

   return D2LAverage, D2Lstd, L2DAverage, L2Dstd
```

<start_script.py> - Calling the above `do_math`

```
  do_math()
  results = do_math()
  
  # Specify the path
  path = 'C:/Users/AeosFactory/Desktop/'

  # Specify the file name
  file_name = "Latency_Results" + "_" + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S')) + ".txt"

  # Create a file at specified location and do comparison
  with open (os.path.join(path, file_name), 'a+') as Latency_Results:
    if results[0] <= 85:
      Latency_Results.write("Pass" + " - " + "4 Screens, Image Mode 1, Surgery, Live, HC, D2L Average:" + " " + str(round(D2LAverage,2)) + '\n')
    else: 
      Latency_Results.write("Fail" + " - " + "4 Screens, Image Mode 1, Surgery, Live, HC, D2L Average:" + " " + str(round(D2LAverage,2)) + '\n')
    if D2Lstd <= 10:
      Latency_Results.write("Pass" + " - " + "4 Screens, Image Mode 1, Surgery, Live, HC, D2L Standard Deviation:" + " " + str(round(D2Lstd,2)) + '\n')
    else:
      Latency_Results.write("Fail" + " - " + "4 Screens, Image Mode 1, Surgery, Live, HC, D2L Standard Deviation:" + " " + str(round(D2Lstd,2)) + '\n') 

    if L2DAverage <= 85:
      Latency_Results.write("Pass" + " - " + "4 Screens, Image Mode 1, Surgery, Live, HC, L2D Average:" + " " + str(round(L2DAverage,2)) + '\n')
    else:
      Latency_Results.write("Fail" + " - " + "4 Screens, Image Mode 1, Surgery, Live, HC, L2D Average:" + " " + str(round(L2DAverage,2)) + '\n') 
    if L2Dstd <= 10:
      Latency_Results.write("Pass" + " - " + "4 Screens, Image Mode 1, Surgery, Live, HC, L2D Standard Deviation:" + " " + str(round(L2Dstd,2)) + '\n' + '\n')
    else:
      Latency_Results.write("Fail" + " - " + "4 Screens, Image Mode 1, Surgery, Live, HC, L2D Standard Deviation:" + " " + str(round(L2Dstd,2)) + '\n' + '\n')
```

Comment: It looks you forgot to index the `results` after having done it for `results[0]`.

Comment: You can try keeping it that way, by unpacking your results like this:

Comment: `D2LAverage, D2Lstd, L2DAverage, L2Dstd = results` after calling  `do_math`.

Comment: Then replace `results[0]` with `D2LAverage`

Answer (score 1):

With the exception of global variables, variables aren't shared between python files. If you look in `start_script.py` you never define D2LAverage anywhere. When you attempt to use it during your if statements you raise an error because Python "doesn't know what you're talking about". I think what caught you up is thinking that the name of the values returned is exposed in the scope of where the function was called. All that gets returned is the return value itself.

At the end of `do_math()` you have the line `return D2LAverage, D2Lstd, L2DAverage, L2Dstd`, because Python only allows 1 return value per function these get packaged into a tuple.

In `start_script.py` you call `do_math()` twice,

- once without capturing the return value
- once where you assign the return value to `results`

If you only care about the results of the function, you'll probably want to remove the first call to it.

To access the individual values returned by `do_math()` you can either access the desired value directly by indexing into the tuple with `results[0]`, or use tuple unpacking to assign the 4 return values to individual variables, with something like `D2LAverage, D2Lstd, L2DAverage, L2Dstd = results`.